# CMD to pick up specific files using a wild card

Tags: cmd

I have a CMD script I have been working on that reads a folder that has 3 different files in it. They have names like the following:
    File1_ddmmyyyy.txt
    File2_ddmmyyyy.txt
    file3_ddmmyyyy.txt

I can use * to identify the files but the next step that uses the file name (Launching an ETL program) requires that the full file path.  It is unable to identify the file (is entered as: file3_*.txt Literally)

Does anyone have and ideas on how I can grab this file based on the Wildcard, then obtain the full name to use later?

Thanks

EDIT - Example-

There is one ETL File executable line that matches up with each of the files based on the file name. for example:

File1_ddmmyyyy.txt is matched with ETL file File1.tf.map (Based on the file name and ETL file name) it is a one to one match (3 files to load and 3 ETL files to load them)

```
DJENGINE -sc "Y:\FileLocation\%Year_Mo_Da%\File1*.txt"-tc Server="X";Database="Y";Table="dbo.File1" "Y:\MapLocation\File1.tf.xml" (FileName = File1_ddmmyyyy.txt) 
DJENGINE -sc "Y:\FileLocation\%Year_Mo_Da%\File2*.txt"-tc Server="X";Database="Y";Table="dbo.File2" "Y:\MapLocation\File2.tf.xml" (FileName = File2_ddmmyyyy.txt)
DJENGINE -sc "Y:\FileLocation\%Year_Mo_Da%\File3*.txt"-tc Server="X";Database="Y";Table="dbo.File3" "Y:\MapLocation\File3.tf.xml" (FileName = File3_ddmmyyyy.txt)
```

In the executable line of code for the ETL program instead of referencing the actual file name (Needed to run) it is trying to run File1*.txt Not filling in the variable.

My only thought would be since I have only 3 files and three ETL files that match base on the root file names I can place each of the files full names in a variable prior to this then use each of them in the executable ETL lines.

Not sure if this would work or how to do it.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: You would need to provide more information. An example is good. For instance, you say there are 3 files, then say you want to execute your ETL program using the full filename. Of all files, or of one file? One file chosen how? At random, last-updated, last-alphabetically, first updated or alphabetically? Can you ETL program handle multiple filenames or do you want to execute it one-at-a-time, or once only, regardless of the number of files in the directory? Please edit your question to include the extra information.

Comment: So after some research I think I can set 3 unique variables one for each file. I am just going to need to figure out how to specify.
    Set xFile1 = (C:\Location\File1*.txt) Name%~nI 
    Set xFile2 = (C:\Location\File2*.txt) Name%~nI
Then I can use them in the next step. 
Excuse my lack of CMD I spend most of my time in SQL this is pretty foreign to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - started off clear as mud.

Then [Taz](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybrDNAr9czc) arrived with his mixmaster on Turbo...

What congeals from this appears to be:

There's a directory `"Y:\FileLocation\yyyy_mm_dd` which contains 3 text files `FileNddmmyyyy.txt`

where dd is day number, mm month number, yyyy 4-digit year number and N will be 1..3.

The requirement from there is to build an appropriate command using the template

```
DJENGINE -sc "Y:\FileLocation\yyyy_mm_dd\FileN_ddmmyyyy.txt" -tc Server="X";Database="Y";Table="dbo.FileN" "Y:\MapLocation\FileN.tf.xml"
```

where dd,mm,yyyy,N have the same meanings, for N=1..3

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "yyyymmdd=%1"
IF NOT DEFINED yyyymmdd for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do set yyyymmdd=%%x&GOTO gotdate
:gotdate
SET "yyyymmdd=%yyyymmdd:~0,8%"&SET "yyyy=%yyyymmdd:~0,4%"&SET "mm=%yyyymmdd:~4,2%"&SET "dd=%yyyymmdd:~6,2%"
FOR %%a IN (1,2,3) DO ECHO(DJENGINE -sc "Y:\FileLocation\%yyyy%_%mm%_%dd%\File%%a_%dd%%mm%%yyyy%.txt" -tc Server="X";Database="Y";Table="dbo.File%%a" "Y:\MapLocation\File%%a.tf.xml"

GOTO :EOF
```

In the absence of any information about where yyyymmdd come from, the above should fill in the values for *today*.

If the procedure is provided with a parameter in the format yyyymmdd like this:

*thisbatch* 20140726

then the procedure will generate lines for July 26<sup>th</sup> 2014 (note that the value provided here is not checked for validity)

The required DJENGINE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(DJENGINE` to `DJENGINE` to actually execute the program on the files. This presumes that `DJENGINE` is an executable, not a batch procedure.